# Width of a float-right box to max width

Tags: html, css, css-float, width

Similar to the question here:

[CSS - Float to max width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146908/css-float-to-max-width)

I'm attempting a <pic> / <info> style layout - but the twist is that I want to make this layout responsive should the user resize the browser smaller.

For this I need to put the <info> box above the <pic> box in the layout so that when the width falls below a certain pixel width, I remove the "float right" from <info> and it should slot in nicely above the pic box.

Here's a JS fiddle of the full-size layout:

http://jsfiddle.net/FNwcA/

Is there a way to make the "Fred" box fill the width so that it buts up against the red box **without using exact pixel widths**?

Thanks!

Comment: For people who read this later on, I gave up, and positioned the element using exact pixel widths, and using a media query for a narrower width, I then removed the positioning which simply made it appear above the display picture.

Answer (score 2):

If the picture div comes before the info div, you can float it `left` instead, and remove that according to the viewport width (with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries)). [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qwuzt/1/).

As the [accepted answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8146946/825789) says:

> It doesn't make much sense to float something when you want it to
>   expand to fill the parent

Comment: Correct.  If I could choose that layout, it would be perfect.  However when the layout collapses I need the name above the picture, therefore "Fred" needs to stay above the picture.  I'm guessing there's no easy way to actually do what I need to do.